# How to write a :within scope for a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a `Location` model, and other models have a `belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true`

So, something like a `PlaceOfInterest` might look like this:

```
class PlaceOfInterest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :location, as: :locatable

  # how to do this part?
  scope :within,
    -> (latitude, longitude, radius_meters = 0) {
      where(%{ST_Distance(lonlat, 'POINT(%f %f)') < %d} % [longitude, latitude, radius_meters]) # approx
    }
end
```

How can I get the `lonlat` which exists on `Location` from `PlaceOfInterest` to write the `:within` scope?

Comment: have you tried using joins?

Comment: What's `Property`? you named `Location` and `PlaceOfInterest` how's `Property` related to them?

Comment: I meant to say PlaceOfInterest.  Updated - my bad

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your model structure, but you should just be able to do a joins before the where. Note the `joins(:location)` and the column name `locations.lonlat`

```
class PlaceOfInterest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :location, as: :locatable

  scope :within,
    -> (latitude, longitude, radius_meters = 0) {
      joins(:location).where(%{ST_Distance(locations.lonlat, 'POINT(%f %f)') < %d} % [longitude, latitude, radius_meters]) # approx
    }
end
```